# Vertx.io start JS Verticle from Java server

Tags: javascript, java, vert.x

Working with vertx.io 3.0.0 and Java 1.8.0_60

I'm trying to start a javascript verticle from JAVA. I found the following documentation [here](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_deploying_verticles_programmatically) that shows how to do it. But it actually goes not work in my current context.

```
//main class
vertx.deployVerticle("com.mycompany.services.DiscountServices");
vertx.deployVerticle("com.mycompanyservices.SupplierServices");
vertx.deployVerticle("com.mycompany.services.ReportTypeServices");
vertx.deployVerticle("RELATIVE_PATH_TO_FILE/verticle.js");

//verticle.js
// from the example: http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/js/#_writing_verticles
declare var vertx;    
var eb = new vertx.EventBus()
eb.consumer("cbweb.validation", (message:any) => {
    console.log(message);
});
console.log("Validation.js ready")
```

In this context the java vertical (first three) are started correctly, when the JS verticle is call I have the following error `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`

- The path to the file is correct.
- Tried prefixing the path with `js:` to call the correct loader without any chances.

Any ideas on how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked the question on the [google group for Vertx.io](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vertx/mKci4e1SIVM). Here is the answer that fixed by issue.

If you use Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
    <artifactId>vertx-lang-js</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Gradle:

`io.vertx:vertx-lang-js:3.0.0`